# CSS3 & jQuery animate on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate

having a few issues with my code here. I want brackets to animate whenever they are visible on the screen on the users scroll. My issue is that all of the h2 elements on the page animate at the same time instead when they show in screen. Below is the jQuery used, and here is a link to a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CbxvH/18/

Thanks in advance,
Mike.

```
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        var test1 = $('article h2 span.bracket1');
        var bottom_of_object1 = $(test1).position().top + $(test1).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object1 ){

            $(test1).addClass( "slideLeft" );
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("article h2 .spanContent").animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);
            }, 1000);


    };

        var test2 = $('article h2 span.bracket2');

        var bottom_of_object2 = $(test2).position().top + $(test2).outerHeight();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object2 ){

            $(test2).addClass( "slideRight" );

        };

        var test3 = $('article h2 span.bracket3');

        var bottom_of_object3 = $(test3).position().top + $(test3).outerHeight();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object3 ){

            $(test3).addClass( "slideLeft" );
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("article h2 .spanContent2").animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);
            }, 1000);

        }

        var test4 = $('article h2 span.bracket4');

        var bottom_of_object4 = $(test4).position().top + $(test4).outerHeight();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object4 ){

            $(test4).addClass( "slideRight" );

        }


});
```

each statement:

```
$('.featureImages img, article p, article ul li').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `offset()` instead of `position()`?

```
var offset =  $(test1).offset();  
var bottom_of_object1 = offset.top + $(test1).outerHeight();
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. What I don't understand is why position()  works for the 'each' statement I put further up the document and not for this. Perhaps you could shed some light on it? I've edited the code to include the each statement.

Comment: I think it has to do with the `position: absolute` you have assigned to your elements. `position()` gets the coordinated relative to the parent element, `offset()` gets them from the `document`.